# Best way to store 'sortable friendly' nested data in mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I need to give my users the ability to enter book categories (from a predetermined list), and to sort their library by Category and by books within each category any way they wish.

In JSON I would store data like this:

```
Library: {
 'Book category 1': [ { id: 1, title: 'Title 1', price: 33 }, { id: 2, title: 'Title 1', price: 33 }],
 'Book category 2': [ { id: 3, title: 'Title 2', price: 22 }, { id: 4, title: 'Title 1', price: 33 }],
 'Book category 3': [ { id: 5, title: 'Title 2', price: 22 }, { id: 6, title: 'Title 1', price: 33 }]
}
```

This gives me the ability to store sorting order by 1) Category and 2) Each category entry, which is my main requirement. (let's assume the object in Library maintains key order, and so does the array of books)

Am trying to wrap my head around how to do this in mongoose. Am looking at nested objects and a Map type one with subschemas, but don't have enough experience to make an educated decision.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to sort by category and title, your schema could be this way

```
new mongoose.Schema({
    id: Number,
    title: String,
    price: Number,
    category:  String
})
```

Then you can sort it by title or/and category

```
LibraryModel.find().sort({/* title: 1 or category: 1 */})
```

Comment: The sorting is arbitrary and user defined. So I need a data structure that is able to preserve/represent order.